# IntelliJ - Module xx is imported From Maven. Any changes made in its configuration might be lost after reimporting mean?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ displays these warning messages at Modules

enter image description here " Module xx is imported From Maven. Any changes made in its configuration might be lost after reimporting." (Note, this happens only when I press the Apply button on the Module)

I want to know what this means in detail and the solution...

**For information Here:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<groupId>me.codingtime</groupId>
<artifactId>NetworkPlugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>NetworkPlugin</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: That you should not tinker with the project configuration inside your ide but instead do it in the appropriate Pom.xml and let the changes be picked up.

Comment: Which part of the Pom.xml should be modified?

Comment: The appropriate one for what you want to do. You might want to use this opportunity to study up on maven.

Comment: Thanks so this probs occur for some error at pom.xml?

Comment: No.  This is because you try to modify something inside the IDE which is configured from Maven.  IntelliJ tells you that those modifications will probably be lost next time IntelliJ imports the MAven configuration.  You may have to do some studying to understand better what you are doing.

Comment: I add some codes please review this and tell me solution

Comment: You need a more experienced programmer to sit beside you and help you understand this better.    You do not provide enough information in your question to help you any further.

Comment: I knew that  but i trying to keep this probs (at least) 2 days .. Could you tell me what information more needed? I just use Minecraft Development Plugin with Maven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that you must not modify the project structure and build configuration like project dependencies, compiler settings, sources/resources directories etc using IDE UI dialogs. Instead, you must do corresponding changes in the Maven pom.xml file.

Because otherwise you will loose all such changes made in IDE UI after the project fill be [**Reloaded** by the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport) from the maven build files (pom.xml).

Comment: Soo... how to fix this probs Please tell me exact ways to solve

Comment: it is no problem. it simply means that you should modify module settings not in your ide but in your maven project configuration file

Comment: So I should through for editing to Pom.xml? NOT UI?

Comment: i got it this probs Thanks

Comment: How did you end up solving?

Answer (score 0):

My case is that I deleted some files of my maven directory wrongly. When I reinstall the maven,the problem was solved.Hope my answer will help some people.